# send data back from secondActivity and update is giving me void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence) on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

hello I am making note app I have tried other answers to questions like this and it didn't work for me. also I have tried Registering a callback for an Activity Result it was two complicated I didn't get it. when I add item to the recyclerview but when i click that added item it is giving me Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

> the point is send data back from secondActivity and update the Recyclerview TextView

this is my code for mainactivity

```
   override fun update(position: Int) {
    val note = notes[position]
    val intent = Intent(this, Data::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(Data.INTENT_PARCELABLE, note)
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
}


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode === REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode === Activity.RESULT_OK) { // Activity.RESULT_OK

            // get String data from Intent
            val x: String? = data?.getStringExtra("keyName")
            val y: String? = data?.getStringExtra("keyName")

            // set text view with string

            val tit = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tit)
            val desc= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.desc)

            tit.text = x
            desc.text = y
        }
    }
}}
```

second activity

class Data : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityDataBinding

```
companion object {
    const val INTENT_PARCELABLE = "object_intent"
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityDataBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    title = "Edit Note"

    val name = intent.getSerializableExtra(INTENT_PARCELABLE) as Notes

    binding.tit.setText(name.title)
    binding.desc.setText(name.description)


    // get the text from the EditText
    val a = binding.tit.text.toString()
    val b = binding.desc.text.toString()

    // put the String to pass back into an Intent and close this activity
    val data = Intent()
    data.putExtra("keyName", a)
    data.putExtra("keyName", b)
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data)
    finish()
}
```

}

Comment: One of your `findViewById<TextView>()` calls is returning `null`.

Comment: yes i have tried every thing it did not work